# Starting/stopping Tomcat using buttons of Wampserver

Tags: tomcat, wamp, wampserver, tomcat8

I installed a server with Wampserver 2.0 which, through the [mod_jk connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html), I managed to integrate with Tomcat 6 (installed as a windows service). To facilitate, I made some changes to the **wampmanager.ini** and it was possible to start all services using the WampServer menu. See below:

```
[Services]
Name: wampapache
Name: wampmysqld
Name: Tomcat6

[StartupAction]
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONSTART
Action: run; FileName: "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php-win.exe";Parameters: "refresh.php";WorkingDir: "D:/wamp/scripts"; Flags: waituntilterminated
Action: resetservices
Action: readconfig;
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTARTUPACTIONEND

[StartAll]
;WAMPSTARTALLSTART
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTARTALLEND

[StopAll]
;WAMPSTOPALLSTART
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
;WAMPSTOPALLEND

[RestartAll]
;WAMPRESTARTALLSTART
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
;WAMPRESTARTALLEND

[myexit]
;WAMPMYEXITSTART
Action: service; Service: wampapache; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: wampmysqld; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action: service; Service: Tomcat6; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
Action:  exit
;WAMPMYEXITEND
```

However, I am upgrading my server, and try to repeat this idea in the Wampserver 3.0.0, it didn't work. Did the changes cited in both the **wampmanager.ini** 
and the **wampmanager.tpl** (which have the same sections to set up), but when using the menu to, for example, start Wampserver, the Tomcat service is not started.

If I start the Tomcat service manually, the integration works, my only problem is to make the start and the termination of all services in a single click, using the WampServer menu.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchanging information in Wampserver's forum ([read here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138545)), managed to solve the problem, I share here the solution of my problem.

Different from 2.0 version, 3.0.0 version changes are not made in  **wampmanager.tpl** . Changes are described below:

**$WAMP_HOME$\wampmanager.conf**

In [service] tag was created a line for the Tomcat service (in my case, the Tomcat 8.0.30 was installed as a service, called 'tomcat8').

```
[service]
ServiceTomcat = "tomcat8"
```

**$WAMP_HOME$\scripts\config.inc.php**

created variable to Tomcat service

```
$c_tomcatService = $wampConf['ServiceTomcat'];
```

**$WAMP_HOME$\wampmanager.tpl**

changed the tags mentioned in original post above, adding lines with reference to the Tomcat service

```
...
[Services]
Name: ${c_tomcatService}

...
[StartupAction]
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors

...
[StartAll]
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors

...
[StopAll]
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors

...
[RestartAll]
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: startresume; Flags: ignoreerrors waituntilterminated

...
[myexit]
Action: service; Service: ${c_tomcatService}; ServiceAction: stop; Flags: ignoreerrors
```

In first test, didn't work. I discovered that the Tomcat service started by Windows Services Manager, but didn't work when called manually by the prompt or through a batch file (access denied error), even being an administrator on the server.

The Wampserver's forum suggested me use the SetACL (https://helgeklein.com).  With the command below, I was able to change the permissions:

```
setacl -on "tomcat8" -ot srv -ace "n:my_login;p:start_stop,read" -actn ace
```

With this configuration, and using SetACL, I managed to start and stop Tomcat service along with those of Wampserver.